# smartctl on external hdd inside ide-to-usb enclosure

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd, ide, smartctl

I have a very old 2.5" IDE drive inside a USB enclosure that gives some buffer I/O error. I tried to use `smartctl` to see what SMART says about it, but I can't manage to make it work. Being `root`, if I just write:

```
#> smartctl --all /dev/sde
```

`smartctl` answers:

```
/dev/sde: Unknown USB bridge [0x14cd:0x6600 (0x201)]
Smartctl: please specify device type with the -d option.
```

So I've tried every `-d TYPE` available in the help summary, and the best result is achieved with:

```
#> smartctl --all -d scsi /dev/sde
```

that outputs:

```
Vendor:               IC25N030
Product:              ATMR04-0
User Capacity:        30,005,821,440 bytes [30,0 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

If I also add `-T permissive` the last line is replaced with:

```
Error Counter logging not supported
Device does not support Self Test logging
```

It seems that just a few models of USB enclosures are [officially supported](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices) by `smartmontools`. Is there something that I'm missing or simply the device implements an archaic version of SMART without any counters (and hence almost useless)?

Comment: For those arriving from Google: Check out the `-d` options, specifically `-d sat`, and look at the [list of supported devices](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices). Quite a lot of USB adapters *will* work with SMART.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is a vendor independent SAT (SCSI/ATA transfer) standard, but AFAIK this is not widely supported on (cheaper) bridges.

There are several vendor specific ATA pass-through commands that you can select with `smartctl` with the `-d` option:

```
-d TYPE, --device=TYPE
    Specify device type to one of: ata, scsi, sat[,N][+TYPE], 
    usbcypress[,X], usbjmicron[,x][,N], usbsunplus, marvell, 
    areca,N, 3ware,N, hpt,L/M/N, megaraid,N, cciss,N, auto, test
```

where `-d sat` is for SAT compatible devices.

The [USB Device Support](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices) lists devices and their command line options, so if you get a USB controller with one of the devices listed as supported, you have a better chance of getting things to work.

Answer (score 12):

SMART over USB is generally either not possible, or is done with (bridge) vendor-specific commands, so there's no one way to get things done. `smartctl` knows about a few specific bridge chips. Check the manpage for a list.

This is horrible, but the only 100% reliable way to access SMART on a disk is to unplug it from the bridge and stick it on a proper host adaptor (like an on-board SATA controller or eSATA port).

With modern OS abstraction it's so easy to forget just how different these storage buses are internally.

Comment: Official documentation disagrees with you - http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/USB

Comment: Incorrect. I got it working using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/692892/478705).

Answer (score 8):

There isn't an appropriate value of `-d`.

The problem is that you're using a SATA↔USB mass storage bridge, and USB mass storage doesn't have a standard way to request ATA/SATA SMART data. So instead the controller has either no way or some vendor-specific way to get the data. `smartctl` knows a few of these; examples include `usbjmicron` and `usbsubplus`.

So, if your USB bridge isn't one of the ones it knows about (and doesn't use exactly the same vendor-specific commands), `smartctl` just can't read the data.

Comment: Curious. Then what external casing (or other solution) could I then use to be able to read SMART data? I can't just plug a Mac OS X disk onto my HP laptop. And I have no place for the 2.5" disk in my desktop computer.

Comment: @landroni You can use a 2.5" to 3.5" adapter to put it in your desktop computer. Or if your computer has eSATA, use that (with an eSATA enclosure + adapter) Or you can look for an enclosure that uses one of the USB chips that smartctl supports. AFAIK, there aren't any better answers :-( ... but feel free to wait and hope someone else on the site knows a better one.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful. I'll be waiting for further input before accepting your answer, but this already puts me on the right track (specifically the 2.5" to 3.5" adapter).

Answer (score 2):

Your hardware "**VID: 14CD, PID: 6600   Moai M110E / Super Top USB 2.0 to IDE**" is **not capable** of doing the USB pass through of the ATA commands that enable SMART disk health enquiry by eg smartctl (or in this link hdsentinel, http://www.hdsentinel.com/compatibility_usbharddisks.php which gives a list of compatible and incapable hardware).

> "Not possible means that the required function is missing from the chip, that's why no further information can be displayed about the disk controlled by this chip." (ibid)

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue, smartctl fails to determine device type for HP Proliant G8 scsi hard disks on CentOS 7.
Somewhat misleading hint `/dev/sda: requires option '-d cciss,N'`

DOH DUH #1:

> ```
> root$ smartctl -i /dev/sda
>
> /dev/sda: requires option '-d cciss,N'
> Please specify device type with the -d option.
> ```

DOH DUH #2:

> ```
> root$ smartctl -i /dev/sda -d cciss,N   # oops
> /dev/sda: Option -d cciss,N requires N to be a non-negative integer
> ```

=======> VALID ARGUMENTS ARE: ata, scsi[+TYPE], nvme[,NSID], sat[,auto][,N][+TYPE], usbcypress[,X], usbjmicron[,p][,x][,N], usbprolific, usbsunplus, sntjmicron[,NSID], intelliprop,N[+TYPE], marvell, areca,N/E, 3ware,N, hpt,L/M/N, megaraid,N, aacraid,H,L,ID, cciss,N, auto, test <=======

'-d csiss,N' where N is a number.
Not sure why just csiss is suggested, maybe it is just the last item in the list when it is trying to automatically figure out type of device.

List device files under /dev to see disk devices.
The N is the last number in the name of the device.
e.g. for /dev/sda5 N is 5

```
$ ls -alstr /dev/sd*
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 48 Jan 22  2020 /dev/sdd
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 32 Jan 22  2020 /dev/sdc
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Jan 22  2020 /dev/sdb
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 17 Jan 22  2020 /dev/sdb1
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 33 Jan 22  2020 /dev/sdc1
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 49 Jan 22  2020 /dev/sdd1
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  0 Feb 10 10:56 /dev/sda
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  4 Feb 10 10:56 /dev/sda4
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  5 Feb 10 10:56 /dev/sda5
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  3 Feb 10 10:56 /dev/sda3
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  2 Feb 10 10:56 /dev/sda2
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  6 Feb 10 10:56 /dev/sda6
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  1 Feb 10 10:56 /dev/sda1
```

**e.g. for /dev/sda0 N is 0**

```
$ smartctl -i /dev/sda -d cciss,0
smartctl 6.2 2017-02-27 r4394 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/sda [cciss_disk_00] [SCSI]: Device open changed type from 'sat,auto+cciss' to 'cciss'
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HP
Product:              EH0146FBQDC
Revision:             HPD3
User Capacity:        146,815,737,856 bytes [146 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Rotation Rate:        15000 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c5005ab90277
Serial number:        6XM1WH6J0000B320CK84
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS
Local Time is:        Wed Feb 10 10:57:34 2021 GMT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled
```

**e.g. for /dev/sda5 N is 5**

The same info shows as for /dev/sda0 except Logical Unit id and Serial Number are different.

```
 smartctl -i /dev/sda -d cciss,5
smartctl 6.2 2017-02-27 r4394 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/sda [cciss_disk_05] [SCSI]: Device open changed type from 'sat,auto+cciss' to 'cciss'
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HP
Product:              EH0146FBQDC
Revision:             HPD3
User Capacity:        146,815,737,856 bytes [146 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Rotation Rate:        15000 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c5005abf9f07
Serial number:        6XM1WKTN0000B320ED0R
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS
Local Time is:        Fri Feb 19 18:46:59 2021 GMT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled
```

Specifying '-d scsi' shows quite believable info also, but ...

> ```
> root$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda -d scsi
> smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
> Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
>
> === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
> Vendor:               HP
> Product:              LOGICAL VOLUME
> Revision:             6.34
> Compliance:           SPC-3
> User Capacity:        146,778,685,440 bytes [146 GB]
> Logical block size:   512 bytes
> Logical Unit id:      0x600508b1001c3aa4f41858962741ed49
> Serial number:        00143802281D760
> Device type:          disk
> Local Time is:        Fri Jan 24 16:11:48 2020 GMT
> SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
> SMART support is:     Enabled
> Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported
>
> root$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
> CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
> ```

Comment: N means a number ie. 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 - as it states in the message "a non negative integer"