# How to check a new hard drive?

Tags: hard-disk

I have a new SATA hard drive. I plug it to my SATA-USB adapter and then to my laptop. I found it by `lshw`

```
 *-scsi
      physical id: 2
      bus info: usb@1:1.3.2
      logical name: scsi10
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@10:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
```

But it doesn't say more about the drive, such as its capacity. How can I get more information?

Comment: Does `smartctl -x /dev/sdb` offer sufficient information?

Comment: Or if you're only interested in the size you can do `echo "$(($(cat /sys/block/sdb/size)*512/1024**3)) GiB"`

Comment: Thanks. @Marco. It asks me to specify the type of device with `-d`. Which type should I specify:  `ata, scsi, sat[,N][+TYPE], usbcypress[,X], usbjmicron[,x][,N], usbsunplus, marvell, areca,N, 3ware,N, hpt,L/M/N, megaraid,N, cciss,N, auto, test`?

Comment: `smartctl` usually doesn't work with SATA to USB bridge chips , see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39064). If you just want basic information use `lsblk`, e.g. `lsblk --nodeps -o name,model,size,rota,phy-sec,log-sec /dev/sda` or, just the size: `lsblk --nodeps -no size /dev/sda`

Comment: What about `hdparm -I /dev/sdb` ?